# jQuery - Go Back function doesn't fire right away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the current jQuery function, which should make the link it is assigned to, work as a "Go back to previous page"-link:

```
function goback() {
$('a').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Although it only works if you clicks **twice** on the link. Or for example clicks on a link with the `onclick="goback();"` assigned to it, and then click another anchor links, then it goes back.

How can I do, so when a link with `onclick="goback();"` assigned to it, it goes back to the previous page right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:goback();">Text</a>
```

Javascript

```
function goback() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the function within the goback function itself, which means it isn't bound on the first click.

just use the native "on" functionality within jQuery to bind your buttons to the function at document load time e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( "a" ).on( "click", function() {
         parent.history.back();
         return false;
    });

});
```

If you don't want all anchors bound, use an ID or CSS Class selector instead. Using manually assigned onclick handlers in markup is considered a little old fashioned nowadays.